# Compile lua to bytecode to run on embded linux

Tags: lua, embedded, cross-compiling, embedded-linux, bytecode

I compiled lua on PC with `luac` and run it on MIPS device. It shows `lua: bad header in precompiled chunk`.

I searched for it and seems bytecode not portable.

How to crosscompile it?

Comment: AFAIK, `luac` is not able to cross-compile.  If you can use Lua 5.1, try LuaJIT, its bytecode is portable across platforms.  LuaJIT does not have `luac` utility, run `luajit -b file.lua file.luac` to create bytecode file.

Comment: thanks. i solved it... linux box has heavy patched lua.  i compiled luac with these patches

Comment: If you have solved your problem, then post an answer to your question. That is allowed, and indeed encouraged.

Comment: @NicolBolas still testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved

Device`s lua was patched. In this case not portable.
Compiled lua for PC with this patches - all works fine now.